# ¿Cómo arreglo el sidebar para que ocupe todo el espacio verticalmente?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Estoy teniendo dificultades para ajustar el tamaño vertical del sidebar en mi sitio web. Actualmente estoy utilizando Bootstrap y Jinja2 para desarrollar mi sitio. Quiero que el sidebar ocupe todo el espacio vertical disponible desde la parte superior hasta el footer, tal como se muestra en la imagen. El área en rojo es el espacio que quiero ocupar, pero no he podido lograrlo.

[image: iamgen refernecia]

Éste es mi código (estoy utilizando jinja2):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- la siguiente línea fue añadida para que la demo pueda ejecutarse -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sidebar Bootstrap con opciones</title>
  <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</header>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div id="sidebar" class="col-3 bg-danger p-3 col-fluid">
        <h1 class="my-4">Titulo</h1>
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="list-group ">
            <li class="list-group-item text-bg-primary" id="opcion1">Opción 1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="opcion2">Opción 2</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="opcion3">Opción 3</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="main" class="col-8 offset-1">
        <h1 id="titulo">Bienvenido</h1>
        <p id="contenido">Por favor, seleccione una opción en el menú lateral para ver más información.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="footer" class="text-center bg-secondary">
        Pie de Página
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', path='app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Al poner el código como ejecutable se ve todo bien

Comment: Por cierto, es `<head>` en vez de `<header>` en ese caso. Son dos etiquetas distintas.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar la siguiente propiedad a tu codigo css:

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Si no abarca hasta el footer con esa cantidad de px, pues configuralo tu mismo hasta ver algun cambio. Creo que esa propiedad te debe servir. Cualquier cosa me dices, saludo!